# SSMS like tool for postgreqsl

Tags: postgresql, ssms, job-scheduling, dbeaver

I'm looking for a database management tool for postgresql that would have similar functions to SSMS.
I'm familiar with SQL server but postgresql is a new ground for me.
I am looking for the following features in a tool:
Creating tables, views, stored procedures, job schedule (like SQL agent job), importing data, sending automated emails.

Much appreciated your help.

Answer (score 1):

Lots of options. This is going to come down to personal preference.

You can all of what you want from the command line.. but

Here is a review of some of the most common IDE's out there.
https://scalegrid.io/blog/which-is-the-best-postgresql-gui-2019-comparison/

Answer (score -1):

Try [Azure Data Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/download-azure-data-studio?view=sql-server-ver15) it covers most of what you're looking for (e.g., Creating tables, views, SPs, ...etc.) but the SQL agent is still in preview, it has import data from files but not dacpac, and not sure if it has automated emails feature.

But you can read a full comparison between SSMS and Azure Data Studio [here](https://blog.devart.com/azure-data-studio-vs-ssms-whos-the-winner.html)